# Electrophilic Aromatic Substitution: Are protonated OH-groups ortho-/para- or meta-directing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, phenols, regioselectivity

In Electrophilic Aromatic Substitution ($\text{S}_{\text{E}}\text{Ar}$) reactions groups that can donate an electron pair into the aromatic ring, e.g. $\ce{-OH}$ or $\ce{-NH2}$, are *ortho*-/*para*-directing.

[image]

In the case of $\ce{-NH2}$-groups one has to be cautious because if the $\text{pH}$ value of the solution is too low the $\ce{-NH2}$-group will be present mostly in its protonated form, $\ce{-NH3^+}$, which lacks a free electron pair and has a *meta*-directing effect because of its strong $-I$ effect. This brings up the question: What is the situation like with protonated $\ce{-OH}$ groups, $\ce{-OH2^{+}}$? In contrast to $\ce{-NH3^+}$ this group still has a free electron pair which could, in principle, interact with the aromatic ring ($\Rightarrow$ *ortho*-/*para*-directing) but it should also have a very powerful $-I$ effect ($\Rightarrow$ *meta*-directing).

[image]

I'd say, if the electron pair can be effeciently delocalised into the aromatic ring then its *ortho*-/*para*-directing power should outweigh the meta-directing power of the inductive effect. But I wonder if there even is any appreciable degree of delocalisation present because the mesomeric structures don't look very favourable:

[image]

Thinking about it from a frontier orbital perspective I would say: The orbital of the $\ce{-OH2^{+}}$ group's free electron pair will be much lower in energy than that of the $\ce{-OH}$ group's free electron pair. Thus, the energy difference between free electron pair's orbital and the aromatic ring's $\pi$-system might be too large to facilitate a good interaction. Therefore, I'd expect a protonated $\ce{-OH}$ group to be *meta*-directing.

But what is the actual situation when phenols or phenol ethers undergo ($\text{S}_{\text{E}}\text{Ar}$) reactions in strongly acidic solutions? Does one get the *ortho/para* or the *meta* product?

**Edit:**

I looked up the $\mathrm{pK}_{\mathrm{a}}$ value for protonated phenol: It is approximately $-7$. This makes me wonder if there are any reasonable (real world) situations where the solution is acidic enough to protonate phenol (or phenol ethers) completely (even $\ce{HI}$ with its $\mathrm{pK}_{\mathrm{a}}$ of $-10$ shouldn't be enough for that, right). I'm not sure if even sulfonation or nitration reach such low $\text{pH}$ values.
But @Uncle Al's answer made me aware that I forgot about Lewis acids and I'd say that Lewis acids like $\ce{AlCl3}$ that coordinate strongly to oxygen might lead to a state that will be very similar to a $\ce{-OH2^{+}}$ group (please, correct me if I'm wrong and the coordination of Lewis acids is not strong enough to be compared to the $\ce{O-H}$-bond). If this is the case, then what about Friedel-Crafts reactions which make heavy use of Lewis acids: Would those Lewis acids interfere with the *ortho*-/*para*-directing properties of phenols? Does anyone have experience with the directional properties of a $\ce{-OH}$ group in the presence of a strong Lewis acid, maybe even in the context of Friedel-Crafts reactions?

Comment: Interesting question. Regarding the possibility of quantitatively protonating phenol, it's certainly doable with, say, fluorosulphuric acid or carborane superacids. Whether anyone does that with regularity, I don't know. I don't think that comparing values of $pK_a$ works too well because they are rather poorly defined for extremely strong or extremely weak acids/bases. It's probably best to compare them with some extension such as the [Hammett acidity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_acidity_function).

Comment: [This article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00399a014) from the master of superacidic media George Olah will probably have some insight into phenol protonation and reactivity. And [here's](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03155678) what seems to be an even more precise reference.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Thanks for the hints. I agree that $\mathrm{pK}_{\mathrm{a}}$ values in this regime shouldn't be taken too seriously. But I think, they are at least evidence that under usual reaction conditions, phenols won't be protonated completely and in those situations I don't have to worry about a possible *meta*-directing property of a phenol.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Thanks again. The second reference you provided seems to be exactly what I was looking for. It supports my view that protonated $\ce{-OH}$ groups are *meta*- rather *ortho*- / *para*-directing. But still information about the influence of Lewis acids on the directional properties of the $\ce{-OH}$ group would be interesting. Especially, since it would throw some light on how strong the coordination between oxygen and the Lewis acid is.

Comment: Excellent, I'm happy to help. Perhaps you could consider making your own answer with what you've learned!

Comment: Sorry for the unrelated comment: how did you draw such nice mesomeric structures ?

Comment: @mannaia I used [ChemDraw](http://scistore.cambridgesoft.com/chembiooffice/?cid=44&gclid=CLSHkbf17LwCFRDLtAodlEEA4A) for this. It is definitely the best program for drawing Lewis structures out there but unfortunately very expensive if you don't have a university that provides you with a license.

Answer (score 9):

$\ce{O}$-protonated phenols indeed direct in meta, according to an [article on that topic](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03155678#page-1). As it occurs, phenols can be, depending on acid, protonated on oxygen, but also on carbon. They can even be diprotonated, when most powerful [mixtures of $\ce{HF}$ and $\ce{SbF5}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid) are used, but not twice on the same atom. $\ce{O}$-protonated forms can be brominated, hydroxylated and alkylated. $\ce{C}$-protonated forms don't posses such reactivity and are essentially [Meisenheimer's complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meisenheimer_complex).

Answer (score 5):

A four-coordinate $\ce{sp^2}$ oxygen with two positive charges is a very high energy state.  Aniline is a much weaker base than an aliphatic primary amine for leaking electron density into the ring.  Phenol in turn will be a much weaker base than a primary alcohol.  Deactivating the phenol will require a very Brønsted acidic medium indeed.

Lewis acids would be more effective.  Anhydrous $\ce{AlCl3}$ is a powerful oxophile. Adding a mole would turn off all the phenols.  One might have quite a time getting the phenol free of the aluminum during workup.  Note the large number of LAH workup recipes to avoid intractable aluminum oxohydroxide gels during workup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It made me aware of the very low pH necessary to protonate phenols completely. But unfortunately, you don't say anything concerning the *ortho*- / *para*- or *meta*-directing properties of protonated/Lewis-acid-coordinated Phenols. Could you add something concerning this topic to your answer. Please, have a look at the **Edit** in my question.