# Is sulphonamide group prone to undergo diazotization?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines, organosulfur-compounds

I wonder if it is not a problem that there is another $\ce{-NH2}$ group in the molecule not connected to aromatic ring and if it can get protonated and react with $\ce{HNO2}$ too, in this case the one sulphonamide group is containing. Is the first reaction below correct?

Should it be essential not to have such group to have this reaction nicely going? - I mean getting only aromatic amine undergo diazotization.

[image: Diazonization]

Comment: Sulphonamide is very different then amine - won't get protonated, much less nitrosated.

Comment: The -NH2 of the sulfonamide group is more acidic than basic so it is not going to protonate in the way you have drawn.

Comment: So it won't protonate even if there is great excess of acid? I guess it will in THIS case. I mean in excess

Comment: Think about how electron-withdrawing the sulfonyl group is.

Comment: Ok, there is no problem because -NH2 from sulfonamid won't get easily protonated, so it won't react with HNO2