# Why does aromatic sulfonation of 3-aminobiphenyl occur at the para position of the adjacent ring?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, electrophilic-substitution

I know that the amino group $\ce{-NH2}$ is a strong activator, so the sulfonate group $\ce{-SO3H}$ should be directed at the *ortho* or *para* position. However, the sulfonation occurs at *para* position on the adjacent ring:

[image: Aromatic sulfonation of [1,1'-biphenyl]-3-amine to 3'-amino-[1,1'-biphenyl]-4-sulfonic acid]

Why is that and what effect does the amino group have on the reaction?

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/152874/17368

Comment: short answer - the amino group protonates making it electron withdrawing and deactivating that ring. For the longer answer see the link provided by @NilayGhosh